# What is the meaning of "you have been a dutiful one these last eighteen years, and luck owes you a debt"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

From *After Twenty Years* by O. Henry.

> Then he said to himself aloud, ‘Never mind, my boy, you have been **a dutiful one** these last eighteen years, and **luck owes you a debt**.’

Answer (score 2):

> **a dutiful one**

means a dutiful *person*, someone who has done their duty.

---

> **luck owes you a debt**

The preceding sentence says

> He became thoughtful: Chicago - a thousand miles away. What chance?

so, together with the first extract, this means he thinks he has quite a good chance, and it is time for his dedication to (police) work to be repaid by Lady Luck.

Comment: How the dedication to work will be repaid  the author thinks?

Comment: By successfully solving the countfeiting crime. He has a hunch, a long shot, and he feels he should follow it up.